# Get result according to if condition in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using following code,I want if status is "0" then i "approved" should display,if status is "1" then dissapproved should display
How can i do this, I tried with following code but not working for me

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('surgery');
$this->db->where('doctor_id',$add_data['doctor_id']);
$query = $this->db->get();

if ( $queryc->num_rows() > 0 )
{
    $rows = $query->result_array();
    $newEntry=array();
    foreach ($rows as $rown)
    {
        $newEntry = $rown;
        if($rown['status']=="0")
        {
            $newEntry["status"] = "dissapproved";
        }
        else
        {
            $newEntry["status"] = "approved";
        }
    }
}
```

above code showing one result/record,like following way

```
Array
(
    [id] => 5
    [status] => dissapproved
)
```

Comment: Please update the question with the result of $rows.

Comment: What are you dumping there `$newEntry` or `$rows` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
     foreach ($rows as $rown)
        {

            if($rown['status']=="0")
            {
               $rown['status'] = "dissapproved"; 
            }
            else
            {
               $rown['status'] = "approved";
            }
           $newEntry =$rown;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing your array `$newEntry` inside loop. That is why you are getting only one result. Try below code.

```
 if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    $rows = $query->result_array();
    $newEntry = array();
    foreach ($rows as $rown) {
        if ($rown['status'] == "0") {
            $rown["status"] = "dissapproved";
        } else {
            $rown["status"] = "approved";
        }
        $newEntry[] = $rown;
    }
}
```

Just replace the `$rown['status']` with the new string `approved` / `dissapproved` then add it to your array `$newEntry`

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
        $i=0;
        foreach ($rows as $col) {
            //below code if you use $query->result();
            if ($col->status == 0) {
                $col->status = "dissapproved";
            } else {
                $col->status = "approved";
            }
            //below code if you use $query->result_array();
            if ($col['status'] == 0) {
                $rows[$i]['status'] = "dissapproved";
            } else {
                $rows[$i]['status'] = "approved";
            }
            $i++;
        }
        echo'<pre>';print_r($rows);die;
```

Please read commented part first

Answer (score 0):

In the above model query change $queryc to $query like

```
if ( $queryc->num_rows() > 0 ) Instead if ( $query->num_rows() > 0 )
```